# Return list of categories and descriptions and set current page item

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to return a list of all categories and the category descriptions to build a sub navigation. My code below does this but I want to be able to highlight the current category by adding a class on the li element. How can I do this?

```
<ul class="category-list">
        <?php
        $categories = get_categories('exclude=9&title_li=');
        foreach ($categories as $cat) {
                echo "<li><a href=\"".$cat->category_nicename."\">".$cat->cat_name."<p>".$cat->category_description."</p></a></li>";
        }
        ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If $name is the name you want to highlight,

```
<?php 
$name = get_query_vars('category');  //applying what the other answer used
?>

<ul class="category-list">
<?php
    $categories = get_categories('exclude=9&title_li=');
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
        if($cat->cat_name == $name) {  //this might have to be $cat->category_nicename
            echo "<li class=\"highlighted\">";
        } else {
            echo "<li>";
        }
        echo "<a href=\"".$cat->category_nicename."\">".$cat->cat_name <p>".$cat->category_description."</p></a></li>";
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that does not highlight any list items.

Comment: Doesn't work. It seems like you are missing a variable for name.

Comment: @MGDTech *You* are supposed to supply the name.

Comment: If I use wp_list_categories(''); I can get a list item that has a selected state.

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress you can register a menu for the same, and then add all the categories and subcategories to list,

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus

That way all current class and other navigation will be available by default.

If you don't want to follow that much, you can use queried category from url and then check and highlight the same.

```
   $current_cat = get_query_vars('category'); //please confirm if its category or cat
```

then in your loop, check

```
   foreach ($categories as $cat) { 
       $class = ( $cat->slug == $current_cat ) ? 'current-item' : ''; ?>
       <li class="<?php echo $class; ?>" > 
         <a href="<?php get_category_link( $cat->term_id ); ?>">
            <?php echo $cat->name; ?>
            <p>".$cat->description."</p>
         </a>
       </li><?php
   }
```